# Why can't I access list element

Tags: python, list

I am trying to access list element from the token variable, but I keep on getting the error

```
 print token[0]
IndexError: list index out of range'
```

When I try to access the element from token list.

The contents of the file rebase file are:

```
ZraI       3 GAC'GTC        0 !  AatII                            >INV 
;ZrmI      3 AGT'ACT        0 !  ScaI,AssI,BmcAI                   >I
```

and the code is:

```
 with open (rebase_file, 'r') as rebase:
     lines = rebase.readlines()
     string  = ''
     for line in lines:
         token = line.split()
         print token[0]
```

Comment: Don't do `rebase.readlines()` then iterate through the result of that, just do `for line in rebase`.

Comment: for debugging try printing line only, `print line`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You encountered an empty line:

```
>>> ''.split()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Simply test for this with `if line.strip():`:

```
with open (rebase_file, 'r') as rebase:
    for line in rebase:
        if line.strip():
            token = line.split()
            print token[0]
```

Note that I loop over the file directly instead of reading it all into memory in one go as well.

Comment: `... token = line.split(); if token: ...` might be better

Comment: @gorlum0: perhaps, depends on what else is being done. Not enough context to call, really.

Answer (score 2):

You may have an empty line, check for this.

Comment: Yes, Indeed empty lines was source of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like line fits this description from the python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html):

splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns []

which means that token is an empty array and token[0] is out of range.